# adding the median as text to plotly express px.box facets

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, plotly-express

How would I add the median values for each of the 3 target categories and each of the 4 faceted subplots? I would like to add the values at the bottom of the subplots or to right of the boxes.

```py
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

data = load_iris(as_frame=True)
df = data.data.assign(target=data.target)

melted_df = df.melt(id_vars='target')

px.box(melted_df, x='target', y='value', facet_col='variable', height=500)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the basic function of the boxplot does not have the ability to display the median directly, I used annotations to handle this. Create a data frame for the median. Create a list of graph names for the extraction and use them as conditions. Created a list of axis names for each of the subplots to use in the loop. The text position of ax=40 is not valid because the display position of each x-axis is different. This is an unknown cause. So I changed the color of the text to a color that can be recognized even if they overlap. This is for you to adjust.

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

data = load_iris(as_frame=True)
df = data.data.assign(target=data.target)

melted_df = df.melt(id_vars='target')
# median data
median_df = melted_df.groupby(['variable','target'])['value'].median().to_frame('median').reset_index()

fig = px.box(melted_df, x='target', y='value', facet_col='variable', height=500)

graph_name = [fig.layout['annotations'][i]['text'][9:] for i in range(4)]
xref = sum([['x1']*3,['x2']*3,['x3']*3,['x4']*3],[])
yref = sum([['y1']*3,['y2']*3,['y3']*3,['y4']*3],[])

i = 0
for name in graph_name:
    dfm = median_df.query('variable == @name')
    for row in dfm.itertuples(name=None):
        fig.add_annotation(
            dict(x=row[2],
                 y=row[3],
                 xref=xref[i],
                 yref=yref[i],
                 text=str(row[3]),
                 font=dict(color='red'),
                 showarrow=False,
                 ax=40))
        i += 1

fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I think there are many approaches to looping to annotate. Please try different ones. If my answer is helpful to you, please click the check mark on the answer to accept the answer.

Comment: thanks for you help!

Answer (score 0):

Posting a refactored version of @r-beginners solution. Thanks again!

```py
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

data = load_iris(as_frame=True)
df = data.data.assign(target=data.target)

melted_df = df.melt(id_vars='target')
median_df = melted_df.groupby(['variable','target'])['value'].median().to_frame('median')


fig = px.box(melted_df, x='target', y='value', facet_col='variable', height=500)

for i, annotation in enumerate(fig.layout['annotations']):
    
    variable = annotation['text'].replace('variable=', '')
    
    for (target_category, value) in median_df.loc[(variable,)].itertuples(name=None): 
        fig.add_annotation(
            dict(x=target_category,
                 y=value,
                 xref='x' + str(i + 1),
                 yref='y' + str(i + 1),
                 text=str(value),
                 font=dict(color='red'),
                 showarrow=False,
                 ax=40))

    
fig.show()
```